# When a combobox is chosen a openFileDialog must appear

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have made a method so that when you click on *Browse From File* the openDialogBox appear. But it does not . What is wrong ?

[image]

This is the method that I made to Open the OpenFileDialog:

```
  public void Lista()
        {
            string[] col2 = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

                    if (col2[i] == "Browse From File...")
                    {
                        DialogResult result2 = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
                        if (result2 == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                           // filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                        }
        }
        }
```

This is the method where I call the method Lista.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //  opens window **BROWSE**

                openFileDialog1.Title = "Choose File CSV  ";

                string filename = "";
                DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                    textBox1.Text = filename;






                    string line;
                    // Read the file and display it line by line.


                    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(textBox1.Text);

                    stringforData = file.ReadLine();     
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        //read inside the table
                        fileList.Add(line.Split(';'));
                    }

                    file.Close();



                    this.ToDataGrid();
                    this.Lista();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through to see how far you get?  Does it attempt to openFileDialog2.ShowDialog() and the dialog doesn't appear?  I'm a little confused with what is happening because Lista is just looping values and checking for your text.  I would think that would go into an event listener for the combo box.

Comment: @Josh I cant step over or into anything. I suppose this happens because alla the thing are choosen with the mouse. Lista is checking for values and when it finds the right one(Browse From File) it must open the OpenFileDialog. How can I do the event listener thing ?

Comment: I'm hoping this is a DataGridView rather than a DataGrid or this could get weird...

I think if you set a breakpoint on the for loop in Lista, you will see that it gets hit as soon as you are done selecting your CSV file, rather than when a selection changes in the datagridview combobox.

Each combobox would normally have it's own SelectedValueChanged and SelectedIndexChanged events you could wire up to.  But, with being in a DataGridView, you may have to handle the CellValueChanged event and put the OpenFileDialog in there if the value of the cell is your Browse text.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView by only having one editing control for all the rows. Here's how I handled a similar situation, First try a delegate to the EditControlShowing event

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new  OpenFileDialog();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ID", "Product ID");

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboxboxCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    comboxboxCol.HeaderText = "Type";
    comboxboxCol.Items.Add("Obj1");
    comboxboxCol.Items.Add("Obj2");
    comboxboxCol.Items.Add("Obj3");

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboxboxCol);

    dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(Grid_EditingControlShowing);
    }

    void Grid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null)
        {
            // the event to handle combo changes
            EventHandler comboDelegate = new EventHandler(
                (cbSender, args) =>
                {
                    ofd.ShowDialog();
                });

            // register the event with the editing control
            combo.SelectedValueChanged += comboDelegate;

        }

    }
}
```

}

Hope this will solve your Issue